# Delete empty subfolders, keep parent folder

Tags: command-line, bash, rsync, find

When I use

```
find /home/user/parentdir -type d -empty -delete
```

it looks recursively for empty subfolders inside `/home/user/parentdir` and deletes them. But if `/home/user/parentdir` is also empty, it deletes the `parentdir` folder too, which is undesirable for me.

I want to keep this `parentdir` to `rsync` some files to backup or cloud. After processing, I need to delete the empty folders, but seems unproductive to recreate `parentdir` every time.

Any suggestions to keep `parentdir`? I thought about creating a `.nocopy` file inside it and exclude it from `rsync`, but looks like overkill. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: if you add a forward slash / to the end of /parentdir (ie /parentdir/)does that make a difference?

Comment: `-mindepth 1` ?

Comment: @Graham /parentdir/ deletes parentdir too, so makes no difference.

Comment: ah, I see I missed the * at the end  which @Amourk mentions in his answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simply do `find /home/user/parentdir -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -delete`.

Look:

```
$ mkdir -p test1/test2
$ find test1 -type d
test1
test1/test2
$ find test1 -mindepth 1  -type d
test1/test2
```

The `find /home/user/parentdir/*` [in AmourK’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174335) is undesirable when there are a lot of files and it is overcomplicated.

Answer (score 15):

By adding `/*` to the end of `parentdir`, you are performing the action on all subdirs of parentdir rather than on `parentdir` itself. And so in the same way `/home/user/` is not deleted in the old command, `parentdir` will not be not be deleted in the command below.
`*` is called a glob operator and it matches any string of characters.

`find /home/user/parentdir/* -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: One thing to be aware of with this approach is if there is a **large** number of files in `/home/user/parentdir/`, the expanded glob may exceed `ARG_MAX`, resulting in an *argument list too long* error. You could reduce the chance of that happening by changing the glob to `*/` so that it matches directories only.

Comment: Also beware that this will not find any children starting with a dot. And someday you will realize this, and if you also do a find for ".*" you will be in a huge world of hurt (because ".*" matches ".."). Ask me how I know.

Comment: @GlennWillen why do I think we should be sitting at a bar with drinks in front of us before I ask you to tell this story?

Comment: @MontyHarder It fortunately wasn't as bad as it could have been. It was on my first Unix system, which was a Solaris machine owned by my high school. Thank god I wasn't running 'rm', but rather 'chown'. I was using root to try to fix ownership of everything in my home directory. Instead I gave myself ownership of EVERY home directory (and all their contents) and then had to put them all back.

Comment: I had a co-worker training a new employee on how to install a piece of software.  It involved going to `/tmp`, creating a subdirectory, unpacking a gzipped tarball there, running the installer, and cleaning up.  The newbie thought `rm -rf /tmp/foo-install` was the right way to do that, and as the experienced hand said "Noooooo" in his best Darth-Vader-at-the-end-of-Episode-III impression, the newb found out the hard way how close the / and Enter keys were to each other.  We had to boot from the backup software's restore disk and reload the whole server from tape.

Answer (score 0):

if you have php-cli installed,

```
printf %s $(pwd) | php -r 'function f(string $dir){var_dump($dir);$dir.=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;foreach(glob("$dir*",GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $d){f($d);}global $original;if(substr($dir,0,-strlen(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))!==$original && empty(glob("$dir*"))){rmdir($dir);}}f(($original=stream_get_contents(STDIN)));'
```

Comment: you wanted `foreach (RecursiveIteratorIterator(RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir)) as $p) if (empty($skipped)) $skipped = TRUE; elseif ($p->isDir()) @rmdir($p->getPathname());` or something close to that. `$skipped` takes care of skipping the first one, `@rmdir` attempts to remove a dir and silently (that's the @) fails if not empty.

Answer (score 0):

When you only need one level (leaving a parent folder, but deleting empty child folders), an easy trick is to use `rmdir`.

```
rmdir parent/*
```

Deletes all empty subfolders, but only prints an error for files and non-empty  folders.

This does not work recursively, but when knowing your folder structure it may be the fastest way to do something like

```
rmdir parent/*/*/* # deletes parent/a/b/c when empty
rmdir parent/*/* # deletes parent/a/b when it is now empty
rmdir parent/* # deletes parent/a when it is now empty
```

Advantage: Easy to remember, fast to type, little potential for choosing a wrong parameter.
Disadvantage: Less flexible, possibly a lot of error messages in your terminal.